# How do I get Ubuntu Time at other locations?

Tags: 15.04, time

Ubuntu time in other locations is not working.

It used to work in Ubuntu 14.10 but am unable to add time for other locations in 15.04.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its working now.

Thanks everyone. I'm marking this solved & closed. The latest updates seemed to have fixed this issue.

:)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `tzselect` command, it will prompt you about zones to choose to show the time in it.

```
   tzselect  is  called  without any parameters from the shell. It shows a
   list of about one dozen geographic areas one can roughly  recognize  as
   continents.  After  choosing  a  geographic  area  by number, a list of
   countries and cities in this area will be shown.

   You can press the Enter key to reprint the list. To choose a  timezone,
   just  press  the number left to it.  If your input is invalid, the list
   will be reprinted.

   You may press Ctrl-C to interrupt the script at any time.
```

**But** note this from `man tzselect`:

```
   Note that tzselect will not actually change the timezone for  you.  Use
   'dpkg-reconfigure tzdata' to achieve this.
```

So in order to change your timezone you should use the command:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have been able to set my primary time correcectly however, I can't add a secondary location for time like I did in previous versions.  I'm sorry my question was not clear & perhaps misunderstood. Please let me rephrase: I cannot add any locations in "Time in other locations"

In Time & Date settings hitting "Choose Locations..." and typing anything into the free space doesn't pop up any autocomplete. Timezones don't work, cities don't work. Nothing.
If I add a location and close the window it is not saved.

Comment: I think these people have a similar problem, but I could not get a solution from those resources. (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-control-center/+bug/1440157

Duplicates of this bug
Bug #1472027
Bug #1473644 )

Comment: Anyone, please??